# How to properly handle the socket disconnected event when use the queue to process the logic

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, event-handling

I am implementing a TCP server in C# and using a queue to process the received data.
That is, from async receive callback, queue an event in a thread safe queue structure, from main thread, process the queue, pop up the event and process it by doing some logic stuff then send data back.
For disconnected callback, a corresponding event is also enqueued.
However, because socket is already disconnected, when send data, there will be an exception throw out.

I am wondering is there any better approach can handle such kind of condition in an event based framework?

I could use try catch in every send, but it is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your send non-blocking, return success on a successful initiate, and then a completion/failed event. May be a wrapper, so just one try-catch.